# Spark accessing views on top of Parquet table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is fact table (FACT_TABLE) with Parquet file format. I have created a view VW_FACT_TABLE top of the fact Table by with the same columns, when i am using the view spark code is failing with below error message in the log User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation:; Both table and view has same column names.
But it works fine with the FACT Table.
I have some other views on top of text files, that is working fine.

Can you please help me here?

Comment: Can you please share the code, which can help in better understanding your problem.

Comment: I can't share code but the context is. We have FACT table and few dimension tables. I am creating few data frames using fact and dimensions. I am finally calling one action df.write.format("parquet".saveAsTable. Code works fine if i use FACT table but when i use VIEW,  it is failing. In the view only thing i am doing is casting few columns to string to INT.

Comment: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException - Table or view not found` - this error are you getting?

Comment: what is the query are you running in VIEW, is that SELECT, INSERT?

Comment: I get below error message in the log User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation:; Both table and view has same column names.